# Why would a classList throw an HTTP response code?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, http, custom-element

I have some Custom Element code. For some bizarre reason it's throwing me a 404 in Chrome in a part of the code where there is no network activity.

[image: 404 on classList.toggle]

The console says it's trying to hit *http://localhost:4000/null*, but there is no activity in the network tab. This isn't happening on Firefox.

Here's the full scope of that function:

```
attributeChangedCallback(attr, oldVal, newVal) {

  switch (attr) {

    case 'show':
      this.classList.toggle('modal-window--show', newVal == 'true')
      break;
    case 'heading':
      this.querySelector('.modal-window__header').textContent = newVal
      break;

  }
}
```

I'm using the [Document Register Element](https://github.com/WebReflection/document-register-element) pollyfill.

Comment: Did you try it outside of the custom element? Have you got an extension that could interfere with that portion of code. Can you try it with another version of Chrome (Canary for exemple), or reproduce the issue in a snippet/jsbin/fiddle? Note that the polyfill is not used in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks @Supersharp, more investigation lead me to the cause which is below. False alarm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was being dense here.

The bad request didn't show on my network panel because I had a filter for XHTTPRequests turned on. If I had seen the network request I would have known that the network request was for a background image that was being applied via a class. Hence the error threw after a class was toggled.